# Some Chrome users are not seeing the Quicktime Plugin activated for MIDI files

Tags: google-chrome, quicktime

I have a webapp that uses an embedded midi file on the page as a part of the functionality. 
This works fine for most users. But a significant number of Chrome users have an issue where the midi file does not play at all. Neither is the Quicktime Plugin Permissions prompt activated.There is no JS error on the page. Going to chrome://plugins/ proves that there is a Quicktime plugin installed. The users can't even play a midi file by navigating directly to it. Any suggestions for what could possibly be wrong?

Edit: When trying to play a MIDI file, they see a Quicktime Logo with a Question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add:  In QuickTime Preferences under Advanced tab/Media Encoding, make sure "Enable encoding using legacy codecs" is checked....

Comment: Is that other account yours? If so, please [request the two accounts to be merged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) and then you can edit the answer directly as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Chrome and the Quicktime plug-in.  The plug-in would not play any embedded .mid files.  I'm not sure why this method worked, but ....  Uninstall the Quicktime program.  Open up Chrome and go to the web page with the embedded .mid(s).  Wait for the Install Quicktime plug-in alert.  Install as directed then close all windows.  Go to Control Panel/Program and Features.  Find the Quicktime installation.  Select "Repair."  Return to the web page with the embedded .mid(s).  The .mid file(s) should now play as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of Chrome, that  does not help.
I have to switch to FireFox to hear .mid files. Even changing the default .mid player to WMP did not help. Chrome wants to save .mid files to the computer. Obviously a bug.